Custom API Returning Login Page Instead of Response with auth="user"
I'm developing a custom API in Odoo and encountering an issue where my API endpoint returns the Odoo login page instead of the expected response. I have implemented Basic Authentication, but it seems like the authentication is not working as intended. I want to use auth="user" instead of auth="public".
Code
Here’s the relevant portion of my code:
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import http
from odoo.http import request
class ReadApi(http.Controller):
    @http.route("/api/test", methods=["GET"], type="http", auth="user", csrf=False)
    def test_api(self):
        try:
            auth_header = request.httprequest.headers.get('Authorization')            
            if not auth_header:
                return "Missing Authorization ."
            if not auth_header.startswith("Basic "):
                return "Invalid auth type must be (basic auth)."
            Authorization = auth_header.split(' ')
            if Authorization == "YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=":  
                return "valid Authorization"
            else:
                return "Invalid Authorization check username or password."
        except Exception as error:
            return error

I send a GET request to /api/test using Postman with the following settings:
Method: GET
URL: http://localhost:8069/api/test
Headers:
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
Instead of receiving a JSON response, I get redirected to the Odoo login page.
Odoo Version: [Odoo 15]
Environment: [e.g., Local development on Windows/Linux, Docker, etc.]
Expected Behavior: I expect to receive "Valid Authorization" when using valid credentials.
Actual Behavior: Instead, I see the Odoo login page.
What might be causing my API to redirect to the login page despite using auth="user"?
Are there any adjustments I need to make to my authentication method?

Just as info from the official docs: "'user': The user must be authenticated and the current request will be executed using the rights of the user." Emphasis: must be authenticated.

The code does not need to be modified

how can i do it?

Obviously not with auth=user but with another type. I have no good answer right now.
